# How can I read a path from .txt in java

Tags: java, path

I have a txt file. This contains a directory (H: /). I want to read this directory. There are also a few csv files in the directory. I would like to see only the csv-files. My Java code contains everything relevant, I think. Now he does not find the text file. The text file is located in the project folder in Eclipse (so I used a relative path)
Where is my mistake?

EDIT: I make a common example of my problem

```
public class AllFiles {

public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
{
    File dir = new File("C:/Users/Example/Main/Test.txt");
    getAllFiles(dir);

} private static void getAllFiles(File dir) throws IOException {

    // Read from the file
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(dir));
    String path  = br.readLine();
    br.close();





    File[] fileArray = new File (line).listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {  
        //only data with .csv were shown
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            return name.endsWith(".csv");
        }
    });

    for(File f : fileArray){
        if(f.isDirectory())
            getAllFiles(f);
        if(f.isFile()){
            System.out.println(f.getName());
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't think you've included a complete code snippet here - you never actually do anything with the txt file contents, and you don't ever create a dataset to return. I'd suggest reading about creating a (minimal, complete, verifiable example)[https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve], and doing that - you might even answer your own question in the process.

Comment: now i edit my whole code

Comment: This would have been better if you'd taken the time to read and follow the advice in the page describing [minimal, complete, verifiable examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Posting all your code just makes it less likely that people will spend their time identifying the relevant parts of your code in order to help you. What's more, if you reduce the problem to the minimal amount of code, 9 times out of 10 you will spot your own mistake.

Comment: So, made a little example from my problem but I can´t solve the problem anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never assign the content of the file to the variable line.

Change `String line; 
 br.readLine();` to `String line = br.readLine();`

The next error is that you are try to list files from `".../Users/example/Test.txt"`. Whyt you want to try is:

```
File[] fileArray = new File(line).listFiles(...
```

Comment: I want to listFiles from the directory that should be read and open by java. I mean that the method `listFiles()` read the directory?

Comment: @LostInTranslate yes

Comment: okay, but why is this wrong? how can i open the directory that was written in the txt-file?

Comment: @LostInTranslate See my Suggestion think about it and try it

Comment: Now I make a little example java program about my problem, but I can´t solve it anymore. What do you mean with "my suggestion"?  
`File[] fileArray = new File(line).listFiles(...` ?

Comment: @LostInTranslate I mean my answer `String line = br.readLine();` read the file from the file so `line` is `H:\`

Comment: @LostInTranslate Then we create a new File object from H:\  `new File(line).` and call the listFiles function on it

Comment: Oh, okay. Than I understand you wrong. Now it works. Thanks!